# Jqxgrid Export to Excel Error - " q.toISOString is not a function"

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqwidget

When attempting to export to excel jqwidget grid data I get an error

> jqxdata.export.js:8 Uncaught TypeError: q.toISOString is not a
>   function
>           at a.g (jqxdata.export.js:8)
>           at appendBodyCell (jqxdata.export.js:8)
>            at e (jqxdata.export.js:8)
>            at k (jqxdata.export.js:8)
>           at d (jqxdata.export.js:8)
>            at l.exportTo (jqxdata.export.js:8)
>            at l.exportToFile (jqxdata.export.js:8)
>            at c..exportdata (jqxgrid.export.js:8)
>            at Object.b.jqx.invoke (jqxcore.js:15)
>            at Object.b.jqx.jqxWidgetProxy (jqxcore.js:15)

My code is

```
$("#jqxgrid").jqxGrid(
                    {

                    width: 1500,
                    source: gridDataAdapter,
                    pageable: true,
                    autoheight: true,
                    pagesize: 20,
                    selectionmode: 'singlecell',
                    columns: [
                        { text: 'ExternalClientId2', datafield: 'ExternalClientId2', width: 450 },

                        { text: 'RequestDate', datafield: 'RequestDate', width: 250 },

                    ]
                });
 $("#excelExport").click(function () {
        $("#jqxgrid").jqxGrid('exportdata', 'xls', 'jqxGrid');
    });
```

**Note:** I am only getting this error with either one of these columns(externalclientId2 and requestDate), If I omit these columns I am able to export to excel (other not displayed columns), the data types are date and string

Comment: For what it's worth, I just upgraded to 9.0.0 and just started getting this error when the old version 8.0.0 didn't.  Looks like I need to keep investigating.

Answer (score 2):

I had similar issue and it was with data.

Your `ExternalClientId2` is most likely number so I think you should change definition to `'name': 'ExternalClientId2', 'type': number or string` whatever you want to achieve at least it worked for me

I was expecting to have string in field Status but someone typed 123 there and once I cast it to string everything was working. Not sure why it works for ID that I am expecting to be int and I didnt have to explicitly cast it to string or number ...